# HTML tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am returning a HTML tag in JavaScript which has values

```
var code = 'brand':
return `<div class="${code}_label">${code.toUpperCase()}</div>`;
```

I don't want to use $ and I want to concatenate through + in JavaScript

```
var code = 'brand':
return `<div class=code+"_label">code.toUpperCase()</div>`;
```

But this is not giving the expected output.

Can anyone please help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without ES6 you can use single quotes:

```
var code = 'brand':
return '<div class="' + code + '_label">' + code.toUpperCase() + '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your quoting is a bit wrong:

```js
function createTag() {
    var code = 'brand';
    return '<div class="' + code + '_label">' + code.toUpperCase() + '</div>';
}
console.log(createTag());
```

Another solution using dom api would be:

```js
    function createTag() {
        var code = 'brand';
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = code + '_label';
        div.innerText = code.toUpperCase();
        return div;
    }
    console.log(createTag());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the problem with how  you use quotes.

```
var code = 'brand':
return `<div class=` + code + `_label">` + code.toUpperCase() + `</div>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong quoting.

```
  var code = 'brand';
    return '<div class="' + code + '_label">' + code.toUpperCase() + '</div>';
```